# Tridion Structure Group Localization Permission Issue

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 and need to take the permissions off from the user to localize a structure group so that he does not make any changes in the name of the structure group by localizing it. However, even after removing the rights and permissions and making the structure group ‘read only’, the user is still able to localize the structure group by right clicking on it and going to properties. Please help if there's any resolution for it.

Also, is there any way we can restrict the user from unpublising or updating a page?

Comment: Is the user a member of just one group? And is this group a member of any other groups?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions on a structure group control what you can do to the things it contains. Remove the localize permission in the parent structure group instead.

To prevent unpublishing you can do any of the following:

1. Remove the `Read` permission.
2. Go to the Security tab in the properties of the relevant publication, and remove the right to `Publish to Content Distributor`
3. Go to the Security tab of the relevant Target Type, and remove the `Use Target Type` permission

To prevent them updating a page, remove the Write permission, although be aware that editing the page allows them to modify the page composition, and that controlling this doesn't prevent changes to the content if the person has permission to modify the relevant components.

If none of these is sufficient, then you will need to implement a custom solution with either the events system, or workflow.

Comment: "Permissions on a structure group control what you can to to the things it contains. Remove the localize permission in the parent structure group instead."
Excellent remark Dominic as this might not be immediately obvious and could very well be the cause of the access permissions problem...

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the properties for your Structure Group and go to the Security tab. Check which users/groups have the localize right and then see if your user is a member of any of those groups. Groups can be members of other groups, so you may need to check recursively to find where this ability is being allowed from.

Also make sure that the user is not an Administrator.

To prevent a user from unpublishing a page then you need to make sure they do not have "Publish to Content Distributor" rights at the Publication level. If they need to be able to publish pages, but not unpublish, you will need to take care of that by writing an Event System.

To prevent them from updating a page, you need to consider the Write permissions on the containing Structure Group.

Comment: Are you sure that is true? I really thought that localization was a permission that is attached to any organizational item.

Comment: @Quirijn Ah, yes, you're right. Totally forgot about those permissions too :(
Fixed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the response. I just want to take off the page unpublishing permissions for a single page. I also checked the details in security tab. They are all fine.

Comment: Publishing/unpublishing permissions are set per publication (send to content distributor or something like that), you can't remove it for a single item.